# Unicode code points to bytes and reverse: how do you do that in C++?

Tags: java, c++, c++11, character-encoding

As an introduction, I do Java and have done quite a bit of C in the past.

In Java, a `String` literal can contain any set of graphemes as long as you can input them in your editing environment; said editing environment will then save your source file in whatever character encoding is used at the time.

At runtime, and as long as the compiler supports the encoding, the byte code represents all `String` literals as a set of `char`s, where a `char` represents one UTF-16 code unit. (Unicode code points outside the BMP therefore require two `char`s; you can obtain an array of `char`s necessary to represent a Unicode code point outside the BMP using [`Character.toChars()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toChars-int-)).

You have classes for a character encoding ([`Charset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html)), the process of encoding a sequence of `char`s to a sequence of bytes ([`CharsetEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html)) and also the reverse ([`CharsetDecoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html)). Therefore, whatever the character encoding used by your source/destination, whether it be a file, a socket or whatever, you can encode/decode as appropriate.

Now, let us suppose C++11. It introduces `std::u32string`, `std::u16string`; those are "aliases", as far as I understand, to `std::basic_string<char32_t>` and `std::basic_string<char16_t>`, and the net effect of them is that at runtime, the string constants you declare (using `u""` and `U""`) are made of 16bit or 32bit entities representing a UTF-16 or UTF-32 code unit respectively. There is also `u8""` (what is the `basic_string` type for the latter if any, since it has no fixed length?).

Other important point: UTF-16 has two variants, LE and BE; java does BE since at the bytecode level, everything is BE. Does `char{16,32}_t` depend on endianness in your code?

But even after hours of searching, I cannot find an answer: can C++11, as standard, do what the standard JDK does, that is convert any string constant into a suitable byte sequence and the reverse, given a character coding? I suspect this is made more difficult since there are basically three representations of a string literal at runtime, without even going to `char *` which is basically a byte array...

---

(edit: added links to the relevant javadoc)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt may help.  `basic_string` do not have an encoding, that you have to handle yourself at a higher level.

Comment: @Yakk OK, I know so little about C++ that I cannot make sense out of this page... I do recognize some keywords in them but how to actually use it in code... Also, how does it do UTF-16 LE vs UTF-16 BE?

Comment: @fge with [std::little_endian](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_mode) or by looking at the BOM.

Comment: @Cubbi that is not really my question here; say I use a `u""` on an LE or BE platform; am I guaranteed consistent results?

Comment: @lge If you `reinterpret_cast` a `u""` literal to `char*`, you will get LE or BE depending the platform (just tested on IBM and x86 to be sure)

Answer (score 2):

You can convert through using a codecvt locale facet.

The usage is somewhat unintuitive, but this is what I did:

```
/** Convert utf8 stream to UCS-4 stream */
u32string decode(string utf8)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>,char32_t> convert;
    return convert.from_bytes(utf8);
}

/** Convert UCS-4 stream to utf8 stream */
string encode(u32string ucs4)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>,char32_t> convert;
    return convert.to_bytes(ucs4);
}
```

It requires a decent compiler though, for me only clang worked correctly, gcc compiled but generated invalid results (newer versions of gcc may be ok).

Comment: I've a more manual version of this code which doesn't use codecvt but does utf8 decoding manually. It passed cppgm tests but may not be 100% robust, it's also about 20x longer :) Ping me if you want to see it anyway.

Comment: OK, now, say I have a file whose initial encoding is UTF-32 and I want to rewrite it in another file using ISO-8859-1, and check for errors?

Answer (score 2):

C++ does not specify a source file encoding. In fact, it supports EBCDIC. All C++11 compilers support UTF-8, and many support other encodings by passing appropriate flags.

The standard specifies an escape code syntax for characters outside the *basic source character set*, which essentially comprises the characters used by the language. Characters outside the basic source character set are called "extended characters" and they are replaced by the corresponding code before the source is compiled, or even preprocessed. This ensures that the meaning of source code is independent of its encoding.

`char32_t` and `char16_t` do not have endianness built in. They are simply equivalent to `uint32_t` and `uint16_t`. You could say that they inherit the native endianness, but directly serializing object representations as bytes is an abuse.

To reliably specify UTF-8 literals, and override any compiler settings to the contrary, use `u8""` which is ready for serialization. `u""` and `U""` do not have endianness because the values are already baked into the program.

To serialize, you can use the `codecvt_utf8` and `codecvt_utf16` class templates, which take compile-time template flags specifying the file format:

```
enum codecvt_mode {
    consume_header = 4,
    generate_header = 2,
    little_endian = 1
};
```

To set a stream `file` (in binary mode) to encode `char32_t` strings into UTF-16LE with a byte-order mark, you would use

```
std::basic_ofstream< char32_t > file( path, std::ios::binary );

file.imbue( std::locale( file.locale(), new std::codecvt_utf16<
        char32_t,
        std::codecvt_mode::generate_header | std::codecvt_mode::little_endian
     >{} ) );
```

This is preferable to translating before outputting.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>

template<typename Facet>
struct usable_facet : Facet {
  using Facet::Facet;
  ~usable_facet() = default;
};

int main() {    
    using utf16_codecvt = usable_facet<std::codecvt<char16_t, char, std::mbstate_t>>;
    using utf32_codecvt = usable_facet<std::codecvt<char32_t, char, std::mbstate_t>>;

    std::wstring_convert<utf16_codecvt, char16_t> u16convert; // bidirectional UTF-16/UTF-8 conversion
    std::wstring_convert<utf32_codecvt, char32_t> u32convert; // bidirectional UTF-32/UTF-8 

    std::string utf8 = u16convert.to_bytes(u"UTF-16 data");
    std::u16string utf16 = u16convert.from_bytes(u8"UTF-8 data");

    utf8 = u32convert.to_bytes(U"UTF-32 data");
    std::u32string utf32 = u32convert.from_bytes(u8"UTF-8 data");
}
```

You can also use other facets, but be careful because they don't all do what they sound like or what it seems like they should. `codecvt_utf8` won't convert to UTF-16 if you use `char16_t`, `codecvt_utf16` uses UTF-16 as the *narrow* encoding, etc. The names make sense given their intended usage, but they're confusing with `wstring_convert`.

You can also use `wstring_convert` with whatever encodings are used by supported locales using `codecvt_byname` (However you can only convert between that locale's `char` encoding and its own `wchar_t` encoding, not between the locale narrow encoding and a fixed Unicode encoding. Locales specify their own `wchar_t` encoding and it's not necessarily a Unicode encoding or the same as the `wchar_t` encoding used by another locale.)

```
    using locale_codecvt = usable_facet<std::codecvt_byname<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>>;

    std::wstring_convert<locale_codecvt, wchar_t> legacy_russian(new locale_codecvt("ru_RU")); // non-portable locale name

    std::string legacy_russian_data = /* ... some source of legacy encoded data */
    std::wstring w = legacy_russian.from_bytes(legacy_russian_data);
```

The only standard way to convert between arbitrary locale encoded text and any Unicode encoding is the poorly supported [`<cuchar>` header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cuchar) with low level functions like `c16rtomb` and `c32rtomb`.

Comment: Hmmm, lots of stuff in there... What do you mean by "narrow encoding"?

Comment: @fge 'narrow' as opposed to 'wide'. A locale's narrow encoding is the encoding used for `char` strings.